# Add custom image size for custom post type or taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, images

I am trying to create specific image sizes for specific post types, taxonomies, or pages. I have done it for post types and pages but I haven't for the taxonomies. Do you have any ideas about how to do it also for taxonomies?

For the custom post type "recipe" for example, check the code. When I add an image for this post type it takes only the first rule.

```
add_image_size('default_related_and_slider_sizex1_724x380', 724, 380, true);
add_image_size('products_homepage_x1', 432, 578, true);

add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'custom_image_sizes', 999 );
function custom_image_sizes( $image_sizes ) {

    // Recipe Images
    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) && 'recipe' == get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ){
        $sizes_new = array( 'default_related_and_slider_sizex1_724x380' );
        return $sizes_new;
    }

    // Otherwise the other ones
    return $image_sizes;
}
```